# Is it Possible to Update a Primary Key to the Next Auto-Increment Value on Duplicate Key?

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table that contains:

```
Id  a   b
1   c   d
2   e   f
3   g   h
4   i   j
```

I have been using the REPLACE statement to delete prior rows that conflict with my unique keys and to replace them with a new row.

For example:

```
REPLACE INTO table(a,b)
VALUES (c,d)
```

Which would result in:

```
Id  a   b
2   e   f
3   g   h
4   i   j
5   c   b
```

If there is a row that contains the same unique key in "table" as the the values being inserted, the old row is deleted and the new row is inserted. However, I have heard that ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is much faster in terms of performance. Yet I also like the fact that REPLACE inserts a new AUTO-INCREMENT primary key value for the newly inserted row. Is it possible to update the id value to the id that it would have received if it was inserted into a table so I can utilize the speed of ON DUPLICATE KEY while also being able to change the id of the updated row so that it has the next AUTO-INCREMENT primary key value?

I ideally would like something that does something like:

```
INSERT INTO table(a,b)
VALUES (c,d)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES([next auto-increment id]), a=VALUES(a), b=VALUES(b)
```

Which would produce the same result as seen in the second table. Is the answers right under my nose? Is this desire even possible?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result while inserting.

Comment: I have updated my question to include a example table and some MySQL code.

Comment: Your INSERT will never generate a duplicate `id` that conflicts with an existing value in the auto-increment column. It's guaranteed by the auto-increment implementation.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think he has `UNIQUE KEY (a)` and/or `UNIQUE KEY (b)`

Comment: If the duplicate is a violation of a unique key on `a` or `b`, then generating a new `id` value won't help.

Comment: @BillKarwin Sure it will. ON DUPLICATE KEY means "don't try to create a duplicate row, update the existing row instead".

Comment: Ok, you're right. But I don't see the point of changing the `id` value at all, if the conflict is in a different column. I think you're making an assumption that the OP has a unique key on `a` or `b`. The user will have to clarify.

Comment: Reading the OP's post carefully, I see why you make the assumption they have a secondary unique key. But I'm still not sure why one would want to change the `id` in case of a duplicate key violation on another column.

Comment: Yeah, the UNIQUE KEY would be (a, b). So, if I were to only concern myself with updating a and b, I would have the id stay at 1. I would like the id to update to the next AUTO-INCREMENT value, namely 5, and the next inserts after that to be 6, 7, 8, etc.

Comment: You can't do that without a race condition.

Comment: I'd like to see the fiddle that demonstrates the above

Answer (score 0):

> However, I have heard that ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is much faster [than REPLACE] in terms of performance.

This is only true under certain conditions. Namely, that you do not update the primary key. Which is what you are trying to do.

If you update an unindexed column, all MySQL has to do is to overwrite that value.

If you update an indexed column, MySQL has to adjust the index(ex), e.g. has to move data from the old position to the new position in the index, as an index is an ordered list. This involves actually copying data and is more expensive than just overwriting a value somewhere.

If you update the primary key, MySQL has to move the complete row from the old position to the new position in the index (for InnoDB, the primary key is the same as a "normal" index, but containing the complete row). This is basically the same effort as deleting and reinserting the row (to the primary key). Additionally, all secondary indexes will also have to be adjusted (as those use the primary key value to identify the row), which makes this the most expensive operation.

So if you just update an unindexed column using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, it will be much faster than `replace`, as you save all the unnecessary operations on the primary key.

But if you, as planned, update the primary key using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, it will not spare you those operations on the primary key, so you cannot expect the same execution speed. Doing a quick benchmark, `replace` seems to actually be faster then `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with updates to the primary key. Although this might vary with the actual situation, even if there would be a function to get the next ai value there, you could not expect much performance gain.

So for your specific requirement, `replace` seems the right choice. On the other hand, you should check if those are your actual requirements, as modifying primary key values is, well, questionable. If you e.g. just want to do this to mark the newest update, you could also consider using a timestamp column for that, which would not only contain more information, but `on duplicate key update` would actually be fast - and usable.

Answer (score 0):

If you gotta have a new id, `REPLACE` is excellent.  (Otherwise, IODKU is better.)

`REPLACE` is a `DELETE` (losing the auto_inc id), plus an `INSERT` (getting a new id).

IODKU *either* `INSERTs` or `UPDATEs`.

I thing both of them check all `UNIQUE` keys, so it is possible for `REPLACE` to delete 2 rows and add 1.  And IODKU could update 2 rows.